# How to debug rmw segfaults launched by ros2cli like `ros2 topic echo`?

Tags: ros, python, ros2, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a developer of [rmw_iceoryx](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_iceoryx), I ran into problems about segfault when executing ros2cli like `ros2 topic echo /topic`, bug I cannot find a way to debug this kind of problem, see [this issue](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_iceoryx/issues/49) if you like.

I know it is about python and cpp debug and I tried using vscode python debug launcher to debug ros2cli python script, but failed to catch the segment exception.

So, does anybody has experence on debug ros2cli code that dynamiclly load rmw interface?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384441/how-to-debug-rmw-segfaults-launched-by-ros2cli-like-%60ros2-topic-echo%60?/) by [zhensheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/47322/zhensheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

I installed the Python debug package (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dbg
```

If you try to blindly follow the examples, it doesn't work if you just do:

```
$ gdb -ex r --args ros2 topic /echo
"/home/$USER/ros2_ws/install/ros2cli/bin/ros2": not in executable format: file format not recognized
```

So you have to run `python3` with the actual entrypoint Python file (which you can see in the error message) as the first argument + the rest. You can also use `which` to find the Python file corresponding to `ros2`:

```
$ gdb -ex r --args python3 `which ros2` topic echo /topic
```

This seemed to run `gdb` correctly for me, but with the default RMW implementation there's no segfault, so I can't tell if it actually gives a stack trace, etc. It should, though, according to what I can see in the link above. Let us know if it works!

---

Originally posted by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) with karma: 641 on 2021-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moss](https://answers.ros.org/users/70425/moss/) on 2022-01-04**:
Works like a charm, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

your method works on vscode too. Thank you very much!

the launch file in vscode is like

```json
{
            "name": "zs: gdbrun ros2",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/usr/bin/python3",
            "args": [
                "/opt/ros/foxy/bin/ros2",
                "topic",
                "echo",
                "/tf_static"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "RMW_IMPLEMENTATION",
                    // "value": "rmw_fastrtps_cpp"
                    // "value": "rmw_ecal_proto_cpp"
                    "value": "rmw_iceoryx_cpp"
                }
            ],
            "externalConsole": false,
            // "preLaunchTask": "source_ros2_ws",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
```

---

Originally posted by [zhensheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/47322/zhensheng/) with karma: 33 on 2022-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1